# Select multipl query and every query got 2 JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, select

I want combine multiple query become 1:

```
SELECT b.fname FROM almanak as a
    JOIN users as b on (b.userid = a.staf1)

SELECT c.fname FROM almanak as a
    JOIN users as c on (c.userid = a.staf2)

SELECT d.fname FROM almanak as a
    JOIN users as d on (d.userid = a.staf3)

SELECT e.fname FROM almanak as a
    JOIN users as e on (e.userid = a.staf4)

SELECT f.fname FROM almanak as a
    JOIN users as f on (f.userid = a.staf5)
```

i want make every field userid will select fname field at another table

Comment: This kind of problem is highly symptomatic of poor schema design

Comment: Lookup `union`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
SELECT 
    b.fname fname1, 
    c.fname fname2, 
    d.fname fname3,
    e.fname fname4,
    f.fname fname5
FROM almanak as a
INNER JOIN users as b ON b.userid = a.staf1
INNER JOIN users as c ON c.userid = a.staf2
INNER JOIN users as d ON d.userid = a.staf3
INNER JOIN users as e ON e.userid = a.staf4
INNER JOIN users as f ON f.userid = a.staf5
```

If there might be missing relations, you can turn the `INNER JOIN`s to `LEFT JOIN`s.

Alternatively, you can do conditional aggregation. Assuming that the primary key of the `almanak` table is `id`, that would look like:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN u.userid = a.staf1 THEN u.fname END) fname1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN u.userid = a.staf2 THEN u.fname END) fname2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN u.userid = a.staf3 THEN u.fname END) fname3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN u.userid = a.staf4 THEN u.fname END) fname4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN u.userid = a.staf5 THEN u.fname END) fname5
FROM almanak as a
INNER JOIN users as u 
    ON u.userid IN (a.staf1, a.staf2, a.staf3, a.staf4, a.staf5)
GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it really help